# Dynamic keys in TypeScript and JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
// Makes `function.name` return given name

function nameFunction(name: string, body: (args?: any[]) => any) {
    return {
        [name](...args: any[]) {
            return body(...args);
        }
    }[name];
}
```

In JavaScript I can do dynamic keys with such syntax:

```
let key = "jk_96";
let o = {
   [key]: ()=>{ console.log('Yup');} 
}
```

How is it allowed in TypeScript to skip the `:` after key name, and what does `[name]` after closing brace of object mean?

Comment: It's a dynamic _method_ name, and it's not specific to TypeScript - you can do exactly the same thing in JavaScript (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions). The second `[name]` is property access, same as on any other object. It's pointless, though - why create an object only to immediately access the only property defined in it and return the value?

Comment: `return function(... args: any[]): any  { return body(... args); })` is effectively the same thing